# Laravel 5.3 - How do I delete rows depending on the selected checkbox?

Tags: laravel, checkbox, delete-row

I'm trying to delete multiple rows depending on the selected checkbox within my (dossier) index.

This is what I got so far:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/dossiers/export') }}" class="display-inline">
    <select name="dossier_id" class="form-control position">
        <option class="display-none" value="">With selected</option>
        <option>Delete</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

<table class="table table-hover dossier-table">
    <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" 
                       name="dossier_id" 
                       class="checkbox" 
                       value="@{{dossier.id}}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, what's left to do in a logical order?

Answer (score 0):

Make the name arrayable and use the id as the index.

```
name="dossier_id[$dossier->id]"
```

Then you can just pass that array of ID's to the `Model::destroy($arr)` method:

```
Dossier::destroy($request->get('dossier_id'));
```

Comment: But how is my delete option going to interact with the destroy? What if I get more functions (e.g. archiving)? I did what you said above.